# ¿ListView.Builder no actualiza cuando presiono boton?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

soy nuevo el flutter, estoy haciendo un ListView.Builder a partir de un [] que lleno de una BD, al presionar un botón tendría que actualizarse el ListView, sin embargo no actualiza hasta que cambio de pagina y regreso, pero los datos del [] si cambian.

Tengo mi código de la siguiente manera

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(248, 212, 90, 1)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                contratacionesf();
                              });
                            },
                            child: const Text(
                              'Buscar',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: contrataciones.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1))),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(contrataciones[index]['clienteModel']['nombre']),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

este es el metodo contrataciones, el cual llena un [] con el response de la request,
al hacer el print del [ ] los datos si se actualiza, solo el List view es el que no se actualiza

```
Future<void> contratacionesf() async {
  contrataciones.clear();
  ingresos = 0;
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String id = prefs.getInt('id').toString();

  final url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8080/contrataciones/ingresos?id=2&fechai=' +
      fechai +
      '&fechaf=' +
      fechaf;

  final resp = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

  final data = json.decode(resp.body);

  for (var item in data) {
    contrataciones.add(item);
    int ingre = item['costo'];
    ingresos = ingresos + ingre;
  }

  print(contrataciones);
}
```

El TextButton actualiza el estado del [] llamando al metodo contratacionesf();, sin embargo el ListView no actualiza., alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Estás actualizando el estado? ¿Usas setState? ¿O algún paquete externo para manejar el estado? ¿Qué hace la función contratacionesf()

Comment: si, en el TextButton uso setState() para llamar a la funcion contratacionesf(), la cual hace el request a una api y llena un [ ] con el cual se llena el ListView

Comment: Deberías agregar el código del método `contratacionesf()`

Comment: No sé cómo lo estarás montando. Estaría bien que agregaras el código de la función. De todos modos, si haces setState, pero dentro hay una función asíncrona, que no ha obtenidos los datos antes de que setState termine, no actualizaría nada. Lo comento, por si pudiera ser eso lo que ocurre.

Comment: ya agregue la funcion, la funcion es asincrona, podria ser ese el error por el cual no actualiza el listView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionas, tu función es asíncrona, podrías usar `FutureBuilder` para cargar ese método asíncrono o también llamar a setState al finalizar los cálculos:

```dart
for (var item in data) {
    contrataciones.add(item);
    int ingre = item['costo'];
    ingresos = ingresos + ingre;
  }
   
// para actualizar los widgets

   setState(() { });
```

Te dejo la documentación del `FutureBuilder` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Si funciono! Llevaba un rato tratando de solucionarlo, muchas gracias